# How to get sum of multiple fields that have same class and get the value of each summation using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Okay so i have a loop dynamic input field class but i will show how it look likes.

the output is like this

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria1">` value -> 20

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria1">` value -> 25

i need the sum of this ^ = 45

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria3">` value -> 20

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria3">` value -> 25

i need the sum of this ^ = 45

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria5">` value -> 20

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria5">` value -> 25

i need the sum of this ^ = 45

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6">` value -> 20

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6">` value -> 25

`<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6">` value -> 20

i need the sum of this ^ = 65

is use this

```
var sum =0;
for(var i=0; i<count_criteria; i++){

$('input.sp_criteria'+i+'').each(function(i, selected){
            sum += parseFloat($(selected).val() || 0);
            console.log(sum+'sum');
        });

 }
 if(parseFloat(sum) >= 99.00 && parseFloat(sum) <= 100.09){



        }else{
            if(parseFloat(sum) >= 100.9){
                alert('Criteria score Percent must be approximately 100. Your Score Inputed is:'+sum);
                return false;
            }else if(parseFloat(sum) <= 99.00){
                alert('Criteria score Percent must be approximately 100. Your Score Inputed is only:'+sum);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

but its only add all the values at the same that total is 200

** What i need is to get those sum at the same time 45 45 45 65**

Comment: id need to be unique.Use _class_ to differentiate common elements

Comment: 1) ID's are unique 2) What have you even tried? 3) What's the question?

Comment: Please use the unique ID for individual.while iterating use some counter to make them unique so it will work or use any class.

Comment: oh im sorry i also tried the class but its not working

Comment: You have a missing `)` after `i++`

Comment: So is your desired output an array of the different sums, `[45, 45, 45, 65]`? Or should the output explicitly link each sum to the class name it is associated with, like `{"sp_criteria1": 45, "sp_criteria3": 45, etc...}`?

Comment: lolka_bolka that is only my previous code i tried different loops i cant get those values

Comment: nnnn yes thats what i need

Comment: i mean when i click the button it should be get the sum of first two same id, then ask if its greater than or less than 100, next the two same id below then ask again, so on.. how do i do that

Comment: Is this supposed to be user input validation code? (Such that your function could stop as soon as it finds a group of inputs that have an inappropriate sum?) If so you really should *also* test that the entered values are really numbers. My answer was based on the version of the question *before* you edited it - it would've been nice if you'd given all the details up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the individual sums to be output separately then you need to add each one to an array or object within the outer loop:

```js
var result = [];
var count_criteria = 7;
var sum;
var inputs;
for(var i=0; i<count_criteria; i++){
  sum = 0;
  inputs = $('input.sp_criteria'+i);
  if (inputs.length === 0)
    continue;
  inputs.each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
  });
  result.push(sum);
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria1" value="20">
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria1" value="25">
<br>
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria3" value="20">
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria3" value="25">
<br>
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria5" value="20">
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria5" value="25">
<br>
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6" value="20">
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6" value="25">
<input type="text" class="sp_criteria6" value="20">
```

Note that your function loops through all the numbers from 0 to `count_criteria`, but your sample html doesn't have corresponding inputs for some of those numbers, so I've put in `if (inputs.length === 0) continue;` to skip ignore those indexes. If you'd rather they output a sum of `0` in the array then just delete that `if`.

Note also that the `|| 0` you had with `parseFloat()` should be *after* the function, so that if parsing fails it defaults to 0.

Comment: this is good but, how could i ask each of the value like if (45>100){ alert("sucess");}

Comment: Do you mean if any of the individual sums are less than 100 then you have failure, otherwise you have success? The original version of your question asked for the sums. Are you now wanting the function to return `true` or `false`?

Comment: yes cuz i need a individual value of those that exact 100 before it success, if 45 is less than 100 return false else true, then the another 45 if 45 is less than 100 return false else true, until the last number 65, its like when i hit the button it will alert 45 is less than 100, and the other 45 is less than 100 until 65

Comment: So after the `.each()` loop, instead of (or as well as) pushing the latest sum into the array, add an `if` statement to test if the value does *not* meet your success criteria and if not show a failure message and return false. (If it *does* meet success criteria then don't do anything because you want it to keep going to process the next inputs.)

Comment: Please still give a time if i have still a question about this thank you so much

Comment: If you have a question about my answer then post a comment here. If you have additional requirements that weren't in your original question then please try to implement them yourself first, then if you're not successful post a new question specifically about the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, id = identify, so it's not logical to use an id several times in the same page. You can use classes to places id

however, Try to use that piece of code for each input group

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<count_criteria; i++){
   $('[id=sp_criteria'+ i +']').each(function( index ) { 
       sum += parseInt( $( this ).val() );
   });
}
console.log( "sum = "+ sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is works, just you have some missing things.

First, you need to put a `)` after `i++`.

Second, I does not see any `sp_criteria2` and `sp_criteria4`

Here is a working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq7hy4dp/)